# Chinese Visa Itinerary / Invitation requirement

Tags: visas, china, itineraries, invitation-letters

I work-travel / digital-nomad. I want to visit Beijing for 2 weeks. Later,   I want to return to China. When where and for how long, I do not know exactly. How do I resolve the requirement in quotes?

Can the flight out be to some other country? Must I enter on the air ticket booking record? Could I get an invitation letter from a Hostel? What do I do about my flights if my visa gets rejected?

> 6. Documents showing the itinerary including air ticket booking record (round trip) and proof of a hotel reservation, etc. or an invitation letter issued by a relevant entity or individual in China. The invitation letter should contain:
>      A.  Information on the applicant (full name, gender, date of birth, etc.)
>      B.  Information on the planned visit (arrival and departure dates, place(s) to be visited, etc.)
>      C.  Information on the inviting entity or individual (name, contact telephone number, address, official stamp, signature of the legal representative or the inviting individual)
>
> An Invitation Letter for Tourist Group by a Duly Authorized Tourism Agency; OR 被授权旅游单位”签发的“旅游邀请函”；OR
>   B.   Roundtrip airline ticket PLUS hotel reservations；或者往返机票订单加酒店订单。
>   C.  An Invitation Letter issued by an organization or individual in China like our sample shows.

[most useful, but not enough, info on tSE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46743/incomplete-itinerary-on-chinese-visa-form)

[a bit better: reservations do not have to be followed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17239/do-you-need-to-submit-an-itinerary-to-get-a-chinese-visa-and-do-you-have-to-sti?rq=1)

Edit: I live in USA and am here atm but will try to renter China from um Kazakstan i think.

Comment: What is your citizenship and country of application?

Comment: They are only looking for info for your first trip.  And may only issue a single entry visa for that trip.  Then after you leave and plan trip 2 apply for the next and likely multiple entry visa.

Comment: @Tom for 200usd i would like the 12 month dual entry at least.

Comment: You said you "lived in the USA", assuming that means you are US citizen then the visa fee is $140 irregardless of visa type.  A single entry three month visa costs the same as a ten year multiple entry visa.  And China is notorious for issuing a single entry visa the 1st time, then a multiple entry visa the 2nd time.

Comment: That would mean I will only visit china once and during the rainy season...

Comment: **What Passport do you hold?**  That is the most important question.

Comment: @Johns-305 USA and Russian

Comment: They often will only give you a single entry visa on your first visit even if you request more. Next time you apply make sure you provide the previous visa even if your passport has expired by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought the flight in which worked for me. The flight out may not but it is very cheap and mostly refundable. The hostel could not help that much and I may have over-reserved there. I received Multi-Entry Tourist visa possibly because I traveled to many other countries before. I used uschinavisa.com.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to apply for a single-entry visa and then apply for a second visa once you know your plans. You should eventually receive a Chinese multi-entry visa which would resolve your problem in the future.

Don't overcomplicate things by trying to get both visas in advance.